# Linear mapping-injective,surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For the  $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ linear mapping $(1,1,3) \varphi=(1,1,5) \varphi$

How can I show, that this linear mapping isn't injective and surjective, and what is a non zero vector in $Ker \ \varphi$? What is an example for such a linear mapping?

So, I see difference only in the last z-coordinate. An injective function is one-to-one function and a surjective function is always onto.I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is an example for such a linear mapping? Clearly $\phi=0$.

Comment: If I'm understanding your notation, then two points in the domain are being sent to the same point in the codomain. What's your definition of "injective"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the (wink-wink) nonzero vector
$$
(0,0,2)
$$
get mapped to?

What do you know about the surjectivity of linear maps that are not injective?

Comment: a linear mapping is injective if it's also surjectiv

Comment: if it's not injective it can't be surjective?

Comment: a linear mapping is injective iff. it is surjective

Comment: so it's enough to show that this linear mapping isn't surjective

Comment: if the statement "I bring my umbrella if and only if it rains" is true, and I didn't bring my umbrella, did it rain?

Comment: it didn't rain.

Comment: exactly. So this map is not surjective if it isn't injective

Comment: So we just have to show that this map isn't injective

Comment: @Zauberkerl I am going to let you take it from here